# Matrix - how do i make this?

Tags: matrices

How do make this with `LaTeX`?

[image]

I want to be able to adjust the names.. and the subscript.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
            & Variable $1$ \\\midrule
Item 1      &  $x_{11}$\\
Item 2      &  $x_{21}$\\
$\vdots$    &  $\vdots$\\
Item $j$    &  $x_{j1}$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]